# How do you enable a graphical interface for the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client download?

Tags: redhat, gnome

I downloaded Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client 6.3 onto virtual box but it's only bring forth a command line interface when I login in using root. There is no graphical interface attached with the install. How do I remedy this?

Comment: That's sorta the point... download a UI if you really want one.

Comment: I figured it out....you need to partition at least 640 mb of ram in order to have enough room for a ui for redhat on virtual box

Answer (score 5):

First, the graphical interface is not necessarily installed on your VM. You can do

```
yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```

to install the graphical interface. Then you can do

```
startx
```

to start the graphical interface. Finally, once you're happy with the configuration you can edit the file `/etc/inittab` to have the graphical interface start automatically when the machine boots.

Comment: where would i write this command?

Comment: You would type this from the Linux command line.

Comment: Where would you type startx? What software in windows do you use to connect to this linux